# how do i send confirmation email to new registrated user?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to send confirmation email to new registrated user with their username i have code and all details are inserting into mysql database i'm working on it but it does not sending email to registrated user

```
<?php
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
if(!$_SESSION['email'] || $_SESSION['email']){
header('Location:login.php');
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['signup'])){
$signup=$_POST['signup'];   
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$datepicker=$_POST['datepicker'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$city=$_POST['city'];

$validemail = eregi("^[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*@([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$", $email); //VALID EMAIL PATTERN

 //CHECKS IF ALL FIELDS HAVE BEEN FILLED
 if($username&&$password&&$fname&&$lname){
 //CHECKS IF EMAIL IS VALID
 if($validemail){
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email='$email'");
 $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
 $n = mysql_num_rows($q);
//CHECKS IF EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS IN THE DATABASE
if(!$n){
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username='$username'");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$n = mysql_num_rows($q);
//CHECKS IF USERNAME ALREADY EXISTS IN THE DATABASE
if(!$n){
//CHECKS IF THE PASSWORD AND CONFIRMATION PASSWORD MATCH
if($password){
//IF ALL CONDITIONS ARE TRUE, THE USER IS REGISTERED AND AN ACTIVATION KEY IS PROCESSED   AND SENT VIA EMAIL
$alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$length = 11;
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
$ran = rand(0, strlen($alpha)-1);
$key .= substr($alpha, $ran, 1);
}
//SENDS EMAIL THAT TELLS THE USER TO ACTIVATE THE ACCOUNT
$activation = 'activation.php?key='.$key;
$your_email = 'non-reply@mydomain.com'; //CHANGE TO YOUR SETTINGS
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //YOUR DOMAIN AND EXTENSION
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Activate Account';
$message = 'Welcome, '.$_POST['username'].'. You must activate your account via this message to log in. Click the following link to do so: http://'.$domain.'/'.$activation;
$headers = 'From: My Domain <'.$your_email.'@'.$domain.'>\r\n'; //MODIFY TO YOUR SETTINGS
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html\r\n';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
}}}}

$sqlquery=mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers   VALUE('','$username','$password','$fname','$lname',
'$gender','$datepicker','$email','$phone','$address','$country','$city','','$key','')")or  die("Error");


 if ($sqlquery)
 {

 header('location:index.php?id=signup-confirmation');
 }
 else {
 header('location:signup.php');
 }
 } 

 ?>
```

Comment: Any errors ? Did you check the smtp confgiuration for sending  mails in your system ?

Comment: `$your_email = 'non-reply@mydomain.com'; //CHANGE TO YOUR SETTINGS
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //YOUR DOMAIN AND EXTENSION` you should setup your server configuration.

Comment: Did you check the php.ini settings for your mail server settings. Additionally check your server logs file as well for more details.

Comment: me using my webmail info@mydomain.com i don't where i'm doing wrong ...

Comment: @CuriousMind me sending email through mydomain.com me not testing email on localhost

Comment: somebody should delete the duplicate status as the other question has been deleted

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, does $to echo out as you'd expect?

The second thing to check would be to see if the mail() settings are setup properly on your server in your php.ini file or by calling ini_set for the various mail() parameters before executing mail().

If you don't own the server, contact the owner and ask if mail() is enabled.

Some hosts have it disabled to prevent spamming etc. PEAR Mail is much preferred over mail() as it supports things like authentication etc.

Comment: last night my code was working but today it is not working i don't know where i did wrong this in this code?

Comment: @Farhan Dharsi Have you made the changes posted by @Barmar?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

First, you have too many `@` characters in your `From:` header. You do:

```
$your_email = 'non-reply@mydomain.com';
```

and then you do

```
$headers = 'From: My Domain <'.$your_email.'@'.$domain'>\r\n'
```

So this will result in `non-reply@mydomain.com@$domain`.

Second, you need to use double quotes when assigning `$headers`, because `\r\n` escape sequences are not interpreted in single quotes.